# How to set ajax event to onkeypress event?

Tags: 7, ajax

```
$form['name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Name'),
        '#size' => '27',
        '#inline' => 'true',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#prefix' => '<div id="ajax-link">',
        '#suffix' => '</div><div id="ajax-display"></div>',
        '#ajax' => array(
          'effect' => 'fade',
          'callback' => 'ajax_textfield_callback',
          'wrapper' => 'ajax-display',
          'event' => 'onkeypress',   /////////////////Want to add event
        ),
    );
```

Here in example i have to add event (slashed location). By Default it takes **on change** event. I want to change that event to **onkeypress** event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax_event).

You can specify any valid [jQuery event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/).

So, you need to change 'onkeypress' to 'keypress'.

Answer (score 0):

By definition from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeypress)

> The onkeypress property sets and returns the onKeyPress event handler code for the current element.

**onkeypress** is not a event name but a element property for returning the event handler.

The event name should be [`keypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress).

Theoretically, jQuery should be able to handle any JS event name.